# Is this improper integral convergent or divergent?

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

> Is this improper integral convergent or divergent:
>   $$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{5 \cos x}{x + \sqrt{x}}$$

I am not sure how I would find the answer to this question. I am trying to use the limit comparison test, but I don't see how I would get the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is convergent, because$$\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{\frac{5\cos x}{x+\sqrt x}}{\frac1{\sqrt x}}=5$$and the integral$$\int_0^1\frac1{\sqrt x}\,\mathrm dx$$converges.

Comment: Thank you. Makes sense